# Running JavaScript in Python: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python-2.7, atom-editor

I am trying to run a JavaScript file in Python using Atom, but I get an error

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Here is my code:

```python
import execjs
script = open('C:\Users\JASPREET\Documents\INDUSTRY PROJECT\Tribbute\test.js', 'r')
script_content = script.read()
script.close()
x = execjs(script_content)

print x
```

Comment: It would be better to paste the code directly in the question so that others can use it directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the execjs documentation.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyExecJS

The short version of why you're getting this error is that you are importing `execjs`, which is a module, and then you try to call it as though it's a function. It's not. This is what the error is telling you: `execjs` is not callable.

You probably want something more like this:

```python
x = execjs.eval(script_content)
```